# Access database not updating date from DateTimePicker after clicking save button

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I've been having an issue with this and my searching has just caused more confusion.  Currently what I have is an access database and when the windows form loads, it pulls a list of techs and puts it into a ComboBox.  Once you select the tech you're looking for, you click a button and it pulls dates (when their insurance expires).  I have successfully gotten it to pull the date and have it fill a DateTimePicker with the expiration date.

Where I'm running into an issue, is when I change the date and try to save it back to the database. I don't get any errors and I even get my "Record Saved" message.  I'm at a loss and any assistance would be helpful.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class GateTechTesting
    Private Sub GateTechTesting_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim MainTechDataFile As String
    Dim MainTechConnString As String
    Dim MainTechConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Dim MR As OleDbDataReader

    Dim provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    MainTechDataFile = "C:\Users\Jmcn\Desktop\GateTechDBTest.accdb"
    MainTechConnString = provider & MainTechDataFile
    MainTechConnection.ConnectionString = MainTechConnString


    MainTechConnection.Open()

    Dim query As String = "Select * From Gtech"
    Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, MainTechConnection)
    MR = command.ExecuteReader
    While MR.Read()
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(MR("Gate Tech").ToString)

    End While

    MainTechConnection.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing Selected")
    Else
        Dim setech As String = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
        Dim MainTechDataFile As String
        Dim MainTechConnString As String
        Dim MainTechConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
        Dim MR As OleDbDataReader

        Dim provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
        MainTechDataFile = "C:\Users\Jmcn\Desktop\GateTechDBTest.accdb"
        MainTechConnString = provider & MainTechDataFile
        MainTechConnection.ConnectionString = MainTechConnString


        MainTechConnection.Open()

        Dim query As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select * From Gtech WHERE [Gate Tech] = @tech", MainTechConnection)
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tech", setech)


        MR = query.ExecuteReader
        While MR.Read()
            DateTimePicker1.Text = MR("Liability").ToString

        End While

        MainTechConnection.Close()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try

        Dim satech As String = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
        Dim cnnOLEDB As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
        Dim cmdOLEDB As New OleDbCommand
        Dim cmdInsert As New OleDbCommand
        Dim cmdUpdate As New OleDbCommand
        Dim cmdDelete As New OleDbCommand

        cnnOLEDB.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =C:\Users\Jmcn\Desktop\GateTechDBTest.accdb"

        cnnOLEDB.Open()
        cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE Gtech SET Liability = @newdate WHERE [Gate Tech] = @tech" '& CInt(store)
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tech", satech)
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newdate", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date)
        cmdUpdate.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmdUpdate.Connection = cnnOLEDB
        cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Record updated.")
        cmdUpdate.Dispose()
        cnnOLEDB.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: `I don't get any errors` and you never will because you are swallowing any and all exceptions.  `Dim rows = cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()` will tell you how many rows were changed.

Comment: Comment out the catch line for debugging. What error triggers?

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks, I went ahead and removed the "Record Updated" with this and when I run the code it just gives me 0, so it isn't updating (obviously).

Comment: @June7 Hi, when I take out the Try Catch, I don't get any errors.  When I put in Plutonix's code, it just gives me a "0" for the records updated.

Comment: OleDBParameters are positional, so they are in the order of `newdate`, `tech` in the SQL but you add them in the opposite order.  `Add` rather than `AddWithValue` is strongly advised.

Comment: @Plutonix Thank you so much!  It was my OleDBParameters being out of order. Once I put them in the correct order, the records correctly updated and saved.